# I have problems with tinymce

Tags: image, tinymce, imagelist

i would like to use ImageTools plugin but in tinymce plugin folder i don't have it, where i can download it, and i need image list from folder like this from documentation but with all files in folder uploads

code from documentation
https://www.tiny.cloud/docs-4x/plugins/image/#example

https://www.tiny.cloud/docs/plugins/opensource/image/
https://www.tiny.cloud/docs/plugins/opensource/imagetools/